# NextJS Image loading only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, next.js

Images will only load in Firefox and nowhere else.

Here's my import

```
import gradient from '../public/mountains/gradient.svg'
```

And here's the Image component

```
<div id='gradient' className={`${styles.bgimage} ${styles.gradient}`}><Image src={gradient}></Image></div>
```

This is what it shows in Firefox devtools:

[image: Firefox devtools]

And this is what it shows in Chrome devtools:

[image: Chrome devtools]

But the weird thing is when I click the link in "Current source:" in Chrome's devtools it shows the image correctly. And another weird thing is that images on the footer load properly

I have tried using the `img` tag and `background-image` but that just says 404 Not Found.
So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

So my friend managed to fix it. So I for some reason converted the PNG image to an SVG image and that's why that happened. So I changed it back to the original PNG image and fixed it.